# Placeholder text for Input>Select Form Field not aligning

Tags: html, css, ios, forms, input

I'm building a form using Hubspots native form builder and want the placeholder text within each field to be center aligned. This works fine for all the text input fields, but doesn't work on the Select drop down when viewing on IOS mobile devices (tested on Safari, Chrome and Edge for IOS). It appears to work fine on Android.

[image: Input select placeholder and options are consistently left aligned]

I've tried various CSS methods including

```
text-align:center
```

input, option, select[id="idstring]::placeholder, ::placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder, :-ms-input-placeholder, input::-moz-placeholder and a few more.

Completely at a loss on how to get it center aligned"

Comment: Try text-align: -webkit-center; , if wont work, check this for more details https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40216

Comment: @Dave111 thanks for the reply unfortunately that doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your use case via Safari Technology Preview and if it is not fixed, can you raise it on bugs.webkit.org?

Attaching standalone testcase to reproduce this on WebKit bugzilla would be great help.